# Retriving data from firebase ordeybyvalue() without child folder name

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can retrieve data from fire-base with below code

```
Firebase ref=mFirebaseRef.child("users");ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot Snapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String tts=Snapshot.getKey();
                    getScore getscore = snapshot.child(tts).child("gamedata").getValue(getScore.class);
                    System.out.println(getscore.getScore());}}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

my file tree look like this

```
users  >  213654518999134  > gamedata > highscore=90    
users  >  213654518999142  > gamedata > highscore=176    
users  >  213545189239136  > gamedata > highscore=432    
users  >  213654658999133  > gamedata > highscore=754
```

the second number after the "users" is userid. how can i use orderbyvalue with this?

cannot use below example mentioned in fire-base tutorials beacuse i have have a userid folder in the middle

```
Firebase scoresRef = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/scores");
Query queryRef = scoresRef.orderByValue();
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
  System.out.println("The " + snapshot.getKey() + " dinosaur's score is " + snapshot.getValue());
}
// ....    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `orderByKey()`:

```
Firebase users = mFirebaseRef.child("users").orderByKey();
users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

**Update**: it seems you're looking to order by high score, in which case it's:

```
Firebase users = mFirebaseRef.child("users").orderByChild('gamedata/highscore');
users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

See this [blog post where the feature was introduced](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html). And don't forget to [add `.indexOn: ['gamedata/highscore']` to the security rules of `users`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html).

Comment: i want to order by highscore. i think your code is sorting with userid